# Strange UI error with text turning to blocks on WPF application

Tags: wpf

I have been developing a WPF application and this morning a test user reported a strange bug in the UI.

All of a sudden in only this application it has replaced all of the text with blocks (see image below)

[image]

I have tried restoring the application, uninstalling it off the machine and then reinstalling it - but no luck.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem? The program works fine on everyone else's machines (he is using Windows XP SP3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably suggests a font that the app is using is missing, or corrupted, on that system.

Comment: Thanks, it was a corrupt font - copied the fonts back into the fonts folder in Windows and everything worked fine.